# Screen Shot Selected Area

Tags: shortcut-keys

I've just moved from 20.04 to 22.04 and the screen shot behaviour has changed. Previously I could use [ctrl]+[shift]+[PrtScr] to turn the pointer into cross-hairs. I could then select an area which would be copied to the copy/paste buffer. It was *super* convenient.

Now that shortcut doesn't exist. I have to do [PrtScn] then drag the four corners of a selection frame around the screen to capture the desired area. It's a massive step back for usability. Is there any way to get the previous functionality back?

Comment: "*It's a massive step back for usability*" Opinion. Other folks really like the change. Avoid opinions in your question -- they distract. Feedback on design decisions should be made directly to Gnome developers (who are not here).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a setting. Gnome changed the built-in screenshot code. There's no going back to 20.04 behavior while running 22.04.

- You can try a screenshot application with has different behavior.
- You can reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.